# data frame shift columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using a data frame in R where col4 its supposed to be less than col5, but sometimes that does not happen.

Is there anyway I could shift the value from col4 to col5, and viceversa without having to use a forloop, since they are quite time expensive in R.

I.e., if for a given row col4 = 100, and col5=10, I'd like to shift them, and col4 should become 10, and col5 should become 100.

Advise welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your data frame is named d:

```
newCol4 <- pmin(d$col4, d$col5)
newCol5 <- pmax(d$col4, d$col5)

d$col4 <- newCol4
d$col5 <- newCol5
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use logical indexing and maybe a temporary variable to do the swapping?

```
# find the rows where col4 >= col5 (or maybe >? depends on what you want)
idx <- data$col4 >= data$col5
# idx is TRUE for columns we want to swap.

# now do the swap:
# a) save data$col5
tmp <- data$col5[idx]
# b) replace data$col5 with the col4 values (where relevant)
data$col5[idx] <- data$col4[idx]
# c) replace data$col4 with our saved col5 values
data$col4[idx] <- tmp
```

Comment: For the given example, > will give identical results to >=.  Of course there may be a higher purpose.

Comment: Yes, that's why I mention it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 indices <- which(data.frame.instance[,4]<data.frame.instance[,5])
 data.frame.copy <- data.frame.instance
 data.frame.copy[indices,5] <- data.frame.instance[indices,4]
 data.frame.instance[indices,5] <- data.frame.copy[indices,4]
 rm(data.frame.copy, indices)
```

Should do what you wish -- and no for loop.

Comment: The call to 'which' is not necessary and could be removed.